# Disable lazy loading on specific images

Tags: images, performance

Wordpress adds lazy loading on all images. Lighthouse recommends disabling lazy loading on images in above the folder. I would like to figure out how to disable it only on images that I call with wp_get_attachment_image_src in my templates, so that I can control exactly which LCP images to remove lazy load.

Lighthouse documentation: https://web.dev/lcp-lazy-loading/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=lr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can manage WordPress lazy loading with the `loading` parameter. Below code echo's your image without using the lazy load function.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, false, [
  'class' => 'your-class-here', 
  'loading' => 'eager'
] );
```

Comment: Great! It was just what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. Have a nice day! :)